# Codemagic builds are not triggered from CodeCommit

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-codecommit, codemagic

I was following the instructions provided by Codemagic to add a WebHook to CodeCommit. Which includes creating a topic, adding to it a subscription and then configuring Notify in repository.

Anyhow, after merging or changing my master directly no build is still triggered.

Here is my setup:
**Webhook in Codemagic:**
[image]
**Topic with a subscription:**
[image]

**Notification rule targets:**

What I did notice is that notification target status is unreachable. But I have no clue what it actually means.

Does my problem occur because of the unreachable status?
What exactly does it mean then?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you reference this document? https://docs.codemagic.io/configuration/webhooks/#setting-up-webhooks-for-aws-codecommit

Have you done following steps and can you see any incoming requests from AWS in Codemagic?

```
6. In the Codemagic UI, navigate to your application and select the Webhooks tab.
7. Under Recent deliveries, choose the most recent webhook, and copy the subscription link under the Results tab to your browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the documentation here has been updated:
https://docs.codemagic.io/configuration/webhooks/#setting-up-webhooks-for-aws-codecommit

There is a configuration that you have to update for your topic's access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "CodeNotification_publish",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codestar-notifications.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:REPOSITORY"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Make sure  to update Resource!**
`"Resource": "arn:aws:sns:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:REPOSITORY"`

Copy ARN from your topic:
[image]

Apart from that(as said above) this step is important:

> Under Recent deliveries (in Codemagic -> App -> Webhooks), choose the most recent webhook, and copy the
> subscription link under the Results tab to your browser.